# Encrypting large files using RSA and AES-256-CBC-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: rsa, authenticated-encryption

I developed an application that stores large files. Those files are stored in plain text. Now the project owner wants those files be encrypted on storage, he wants confidentiality, integrity, and authenticity.

The application is written in C# using .NET Framework 4.8. There are no authenticated encryption stream cyphers in .NET Framework 4.8, so I need to create my homemade solution. I'm not a crypto guy, so I'm not sure if the solution is secure enough.

I have a secret RSA key pair acting as the master key. then I do the following to encrypt the source clear text file into the encrypted destination file (in pseudo-code):

```
aes_key = generate_random_number()
initial_iv = generate_random_number()
hmac_key = generate_random_number()
initial_nonce = generate_random_number()

header = aes_key || initial_iv || hmac_key || initial_nonce
cipher_header = rsa_encrypt(header)
write_to_file(encrypted_file, cipher_header)
header_signature = rsa_sign(header)
cipher_header_signature = rsa_encrypt(header_signature)
write_to_file(encrypted_file, cipher_header_signature)

chunk_number = 0

while not end of source_file
   clear_chunk = read_chunk_from_file(source_file)
   iv = initial_iv xor chunk_number
   cipher_chunk = aes_encrypt(aes_key, iv, clear_chunk)
   nonce = initial_nonce xor chunk_number
   tag = hmac(hmac_key, nonce || cipher_chunk)
   write_to_file(encrypted_file, tag)
   write_to_file(encrypted_file, cipher_chunk)
   chunk_number = chunk_number + 1
end while
```

Is this approach secure? What best practices I'm not following?

Comment: What does `aes_encrypt` do, as a 3-argument function?

Comment: If authentication is important, why not implement AES-GCM or some other authenticated encryption mode instead of creating your own? Also take a look for any third-party libraries.

Comment: @EugeneStyer AES-GCM is available in .NET core but not in.NET Fx 4.8. This is why I'm implementing my own. Also, I haven't found any third party .NET library that implements authentication encryption stream cipher.

Comment: @Mikero aes_encrypt function encrypts the clear text (third parameter) using AES-256-CBC algorithm. It uses the first parameter as the key, the second parameter as the initialization vector, it returns the cipher text

Comment: This kind of code review would be at place on [codereview.se]. I think it would be a good idea to add the decryption method before doing so though, as they require working code. Happy to help you there, I see at least one big vulnerability.

Comment: Ideally use a third party library and ditch AES-CBC/RSA. Even in .NET 8, the standard crypto library is quite bad (e.g. it's not properly cross-platform). Don't randomly generate an AES key and HMAC key, randomly generate one key per file (a DEK) and use a KDF like HKDF to split it into the AES and HMAC keys. AES-CBC needs an unpredictable IV. There's no need for a nonce in HMAC and the AES-CBC IV isn't being authenticated. Chunks can be removed from the end without detection. There are quite a few issues. I'd recommend looking at what file encryption programs like age and Kryptor are doing.

Comment: Everybody still missing the IV handling?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I mentioned the IV in my comment unless there's another problem I skipped. The issue is .NET doesn't have AES-CTR for some bizarre reason. The [libsodium bindings](https://doc.libsodium.org/bindings_for_other_languages) aren't for .NET Framework, only .NET. There's [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/), but their APIs aren't great and neither is the performance. There's also no C# documentation. Maybe the best bet is [Inferno](https://securitydriven.net/inferno/), which has been audited by Cure53 and has stream encryption APIs with AES-CTR-then-HMAC.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6. What about `iv = sha(initial_iv xor chunk_number)` or `iv = hkdf(initial_iv xor chunk_number)` would it be unpredictable?

Comment: @samuel-lucas6.  I will follow your suggestion, i will use KDF to generate AES and HMAC keys. Thank you

Comment: @samuel-lucas6. you said that AES-CBC IV isn't being authenticated. I don't think it is needed because I don't even write it into destination stream. It is derived from the `initial_iv` and the `chunk_number`

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 I will think about a way to append some kind of identifiable last chunk, to avoid that chunks could be removed from the end without detection

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 I thought using nonce with hmac was a good thing https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/secure-programming-cookbook/0596003943/ch06s12.html

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have working code and I will post to Code Review after I improve the approach with the suggestions provided on this forum

Comment: Yes, the IV handling has a problem. Think what can happen with the XOR, e.g. if I send a counter as first block as well for CBC.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have no idea of what might happen, may be you could bring some light to this. As I said I'm not a crypto guy. I have no idea of AES-CBC internals. I just know that IV should be unique for each message. May be you could suggest another approach to derive IV from initial_iv and the chunk_number to get a good IV?

Comment: This is a pure programming question and that's why it is off topic on Crypto SE. I suggest to move this question to SO.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes. There is a question on code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288754/encrypting-large-files-using-rsa-and-aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha384

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the code review, here are some high-level recommendations:

1. Key generation: Make sure that random source follows NIST SP800-90* guidelines.  In addition, for crypto keys it's good to apply an extractor to obtain uniform distribution on your key space.  You may consult NIST SP800-133 for more detail, but HKDF-extract would be a good choice.
2. For RSA encryption (i.e. key wrapping in this case), make sure you use an approved scheme RSA-OAEP.  You may consult with RFC 8017 and FIPS 186-5 for more details.
3. If you also want to sign the header, make sure you use a different RSA key than the one you used for encryption.  Also, use a valid scheme for RSA signature like PSS
4. The overall method: you encrypt the header, you sign the header, then you encrypt the signature.  Please consult [NIST SP 800-56B Rev. 2](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Br2.pdf) for approved RSA-based methods of key wrapping.  In short, you may simply encrypt/wrap the key.  For authentication, you can add key confirmation by using a MAC
5. Using AES-256-CBC encryption with HMAC integrity should be fine since you're using an encrypt-then-MAC composition per this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2000/025.pdf). Just make sure padding is handled properly in CBC mode.
6. Pay attention to key sizes.  This may depend on your security-level needs and which standards you wish to follow.  If you want to follow CNSA 1.0 for example (assuming you're not looking at PQ), they recommend a minimum of RSA-3072 and SHA-384.

Comment: Key generation: I will use HKDF as you suggested.

Comment: RSA encryption: I'm using PKCS#1 v1.5 but I will use RSA-OAEP-SHA-512

Comment: The overall method. I don't understand NIST SP 800-56B Rev. 2. How to add key confirmation by using a MAC? I don't understand what should be MAC'ed.

Comment: looking at your case, key confirmation w/ MAC may not be applicable to you.  Usually, this happens between 2 separate parties where sending party wants to confirm that receiving party indeed got the right key.  In your case, you're one and the same.